# Java 8: What is the shortest way to initialize a hash set of one key?

Tags: java

Currently, this is the way that I create a HashSet of one element:

```
new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("123"))
```

Can you think of a shorter way that works with Java 8?

I know that in Java 9 this syntax is allowed:

```
Set.of("123")
```

Unfortunately, it's not compatible in Java 8.

Comment: If you just need a *set*, not a hashset, you could use [`Collections.singleton("123")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T)). That returns an immutable set of one element, like `Set.of("123")` in Java 9+.

Comment: @khelwood Worth adding that `Collections.singleton("123")` will return an unmodifiable set.

Comment: @ernest_k So will `Set.of()` though.

Comment: `import static java.util.Collections.*;`  to make it shorter (**don't**).

Comment: I didn't know `Collections.singleton` returned a `Set` until now! I had always thought it returned a `Collection` for some reason... @khelwood

Comment: @Sweeper It is a bit weird that there's `singletonList` for a list, and `singleton` for a set. Odd naming decision.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what's your reasoning to say "*don't*" to the import?

Comment: @khelwood I just looked at the docs and it seems that `Collections.singleton` has been introduced in version 1.2 (at the same time as the whole class) and other similar methods (`singletonList` etc) in 1.3. So they just left it as is for the backwards compatibility I guess.

Comment: @khelwood I find the naming quite predictable, though. A *singleton* is a *set* with one element

Comment: On a sidenote: [`Set.of(...)` does not necessarily return a `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)). The documentation is intentionally vague and only says it returns an unmodifiable set. It should not be relied upon that it is a `HashSet` since this is an implementation detail and could change without prior notice.

Comment: After a short research I found a very nice 3rd party library named Guava: https://github.com/google/guava.
It offers a syntax of ImmutableSet.of(...) and ImmutableMap.of(1, "a", 2, "b",...)

Comment: @CrazySynthax I would consider a third-party dependency pretty much overkill in relation to what you are asking here. If you like it yourself, do post it an an answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a *set*, not a hashset, you could use [`Collections.singleton("123")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T)). That returns an immutable set of one element, which is what `Set.of("123")` returns in Java 9+.

Note that neither `Set.of(...)` nor `singleton(...)` claims to return a *hashset*, just a single-valued immutable set.

If you want an actual instance of `HashSet`, you can convert to one, but then you're left with something that resembles what you had already:

```
new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton("123"))
```

(but without the unnecessary array creation for `Arrays.asList(...)`)

Comment: Very nice account of the options, what they give us and their limitations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `Set.of` method. (Note: `Set.of` does not return a `HashSet`.)

But **shortest is often not best**, which this clearly illustrates.

```
new HashSet<>() {{ add("123"); }}
```

(I think.)

(Also Java 8. Java SE 11 is the current long term support version, about to be replaced by 14. Get a move on.)

Comment: You need two curly braces for the initializer (one for the class, one for the instance initialization). You might want to advise against actually doing this though.

Comment: @danie I do. I think I did. Perhaps not clearly enough.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline What is add? a method()

Comment: The `{{ add }}` trick works, but it's confusing and it creates an unnecessary anonymous subclass of `HashSet`. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not recommending it.

Comment: It does answer the question, I find it kind of unfair to downvote it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I don't see any downsides mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @khelwood I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: "But shortest is often not best, **which this clearly illustrates.**" It might be clear for some why not to use such construction but it won't be for most new Java programmers.

Comment: [Don’t be “Clever”: The Double Curly Braces Anti Pattern](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/) (IMHO says it better than this post)